# Curl to VB.net conversion

Tags: php, vb.net, curl

ive searched everywhere and cannot find how to post data using vb.net

So i was wondering if someone can convert this curl code I made into vb.net :)

```
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1"; 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE ); // return into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec( $ch ); // run!
curl_close($ch);
```

$data being an array, not sure how it will work in vb.net though.

Comment: clarify please, do you mean how to post over HTTP using vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

CURL is an independent application and a PHP extension allows you to utilize it seamlessly from  inside PHP code. So you can install CURL and get it work via your shell commands from .NET ... while at the same time you might find this useful as well.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/dotnet/